# mixing audio live over the internet between mac & pc

Tags: mixing, music, internet

Mixing audio on a DAW.. Trying to connect over the internet to share audio with the artist & live mix. Stereo wav quality HD if possible. Tight sync not needed.... Mac & PC
Thank you GP

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more, like what the problem is, what you have already tried, what you have looked into... etc? Your question is a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question so that what you're asking is clear? It would help us answer this question if you gave some more information like what DAW you're using and how you're trying to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Something like Virtual Audio Cable would allow you to feed a virtual sound device output in as an input to a sound streaming option of your choice.  There are many decent options for high quality audio streaming.  They are pretty easy to find once you have solved the issue of getting the audio from the DAW to appear as an input for it, which is what Virtual Audio Cable does.